# Friend/Unfriend doesn't work unless the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Before everything, I beg you to understand the fact that I am very new to rails. I am trying to make Friend/Unfriend function and I've made it until here.

I made add_friend.js.erb and added the code below.

```
$(".grid-box.c a").text("Cancel Friend Request");
$(".grid-box.c a").attr("href", "http://localhost:3000/friends/<%= @user.id %>/cancel_friend?friend_id=<%= @user.id %>");
```

I also made cancel_friend.js.erb and did the same.

```
$(".grid-box.c a").text("Add Friend!");
$(".grid-box.c a").attr("href", "http://localhost:3000/friends/<%= @user1.id %>/add_friend?friend_id=<%= @user1.id %>");
```

The view file is as below.

```
<% if current_user.sent_friend(@user) == true %>
  <%= link_to "Cancel Friend Request", cancel_friend_path(:friend_id => @user.id), method: 'delete', remote: true %>
<% elsif current_user.is_friend(@user) == false %>
  <%= link_to "Add Friend!", add_friend_path(:friend_id => @user.id), method: 'get', remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

Some of you might have already noticed that in this way, it won't work unless the page gets reloaded. I've spent several hours on google to find out how to solve the problem and yes I know that this is related with something like Ajax and Turbolinks, and I also know that there are similar questions and answers about this issue, but since I have a little knowledge of Rails, I found it hard to understand. I would really appreciate if you get down to my level and explain how I would be able to overcome this crisis. Thank you!

Comment: This one is a tough question to answer since there's a lot of boilerplate code involved in writing this solution. I would ask around till you find a good tutorial to approach this.

Comment: To be clear, when you land on your view file, you need to reload the view before you can see "add friend" or "cancel request"?

Comment: @JosephCho Thank you for your comment, I will keep finding for a solution!

Comment: @SaraChipps Initially, I can see 'add friend' and when I click 'add friend' it  turns into 'cancel request' but when I click 'cancel request', it doesn't work. After I reload the entire page and click it again, it turns into 'add friend'. I am trying to make it work without reloading the entire page.

Comment: It sounds like you may need an AJAX request. AJAX stands for asynchronous JS and XML, it is for sending and receiving data without reloading the page. I would recommend checking out some tutorials on AJAX and Rails.

Comment: @Max are you using turbolinks (you mentioned you know of it, but didn't say you were using it)? It might be worth adding a `data-turbolinks="false"` attribute to each link (on your `js.erb` fields and your view file) just to rule out it's not a caching/reload issue with turbolinks. What you have looks like it _should_ work and the fact that one event is working, and then not the other is interesting.

Comment: I've already tried data-turbolinks="false" but it's not working. Maybe I need to study more about AJAX and turbolinks. Thanks guys!